# Character rig issue

Tags: rigging, origin

Good day everyone,

I have a model in Blender that is rigged. There are a few problems with the character. The first problem is when use manipulators which affect the hand rotation the right part of face start deforming. Other than that I have an issue with elbows. Because it is deform uncorrect.

upd: seems like the problem with shape keys. but I don't understand how to solve it.

Also I don't understand how to move the model at all. When I move the rig in pose mode origin doesn't move so I can't make animation.

UPD: the problem with moving was solved.

I have checked the weight paint and read a lot of qustions here but I haven't reached any succes in fixing it. I would appreciate any advices and help.

The file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HvWl95MOBm0Lbkx11wnZT2S718ikVqBy/view?usp=sharing

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: If head is pulled by arm controller then it must be weight problem, bone that controls arm must have a weight on head, are you sure it isn't the case?

Comment: @MikoCG I've checked the weight paint and the bone that controls arm doesn't have any weight on head

Comment: not even shoulder bone or fingers bone? (If they are used)

Comment: @MikoCG I've rechecked all bones. And nothing affect head except the neck bone.

Comment: The model has corrective shapekeys which are controlled by drivers that react to the bone movements/rotations. The deformation of the head is caused by shapekey *wristUp.L*. It's broken and has a deformed head. You can try to fix it by deleting it and then copy & mirror the shapekey *wristUp.R* to restore it. About the elbows, the mesh is not ideal. It lacks a good geometry for stretching and compression. The rig has no twist bones. Both could be the reason for the bad deformation. Or it is the bone position. The shapekey for the elbows can't do its job properly.

Comment: @blunder thanks a lot I'll try to change the spakeys and correct the elbow